# Rotation and resizing the image + iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to resize and rotate an image over the iPhone.
i picked the image and displayed it using UIImageView

and rotation of the image is done by two buttons (for clockwise & counterclockwise)

resizing of image works fine while rotation button not pressed
but when i pressed to rotate image into clockwise direction and the resize the image, width of the image increases rapidly even i am trying to decrease the width.

and when i pressed to rotate image into counterclockwise direction and the resize the image, height of the image increases rapidly even i am trying to decrease it.

i found that there is some sign changed while rotating the image along with the value, coz once press the clockwise button and then counterclockwise button, and then resizing works fine.

i used the following code for rotating the image.

```
CGAffineTransform transformRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(movingAngle);
imageViewRotation.transform = transformRotate;
```

where movingAngle is in Radians
and imageViewRotation is the UIImageView which contains the image.

waiting for your reply

Comment: Could you reformat the code please from now on. Add 4 spaces before the code and it will be edited to look like code. Don't make it bold from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this happen smoother by making it an animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil contextNULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5;

CGAffineTransform transformRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(movingAngle); 
imageViewRotation.transform = transformRotate;

CGRect frame = /*make the new frame or set it to -->*/self.view.frame;
imageViewRotation.frame = newFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```